# Unable to delete greyed out app on mac

Tags: mac

I  have 88GB of games in the app section of storage that I would like to delete but these are greyed out when looking in the About this mac>Storage folder, when I go into my normal applications folder these games are not shown. Please note the original owner bought this mac for games then after 6 months realised he would prefer a gaming pc. I thought he had deleted everything off it but these games seem to be embedded somewhere.
Mac is a macbook pro, 2017, running Catalina v.10.15.3
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you logged in to your own account?  Are there other user accounts?

Comment: I'm more worried that you apparently received a Mac which hadn't been fully reset by the last owner. You will need to do that properly at some point. Right now, you don't even own the operating system, let alone any of the apps on there. You will get to a point where it wants the old owner's AppleID & password & you won't have it. See https://support.apple.com/HT201065

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Application folders on your mac. One is located under your home directory and the other is located at the same level as Users. On my machine that is 1 at /Users/myname/Applications and the other at /Applications.  I'd check the other Applications folder for the games you wish to delete.